# How to define some function which can be accessed from within the scope of operator overloading for (+) operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c++14, operator-keyword

I created a code by using operator overloading concept in c++ for addition of two rational numbers by overloading the +(plus) and the <<(Insertion) operator and I am not able to get a function being accessed from the scope of operator overloading of + operator. How to access the LCM() function from the scope of operator+ overloaded?

I tried using the friend function to access my LCM() function from within the scope of operator+ overloaded function but it didn't work!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rational {

private:
    int num, den;

public:
    int getnum()
    {
        return this->num;
    }

    int getden()
    {
        return this->den;
    }

    Rational(int num = 0, int den = 0)
    {
        this->num = num;
        this->den = den;
    }
    int LCM(int a, int b);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Rational& r);
    friend Rational operator+(Rational x, Rational y);
};

int Rational::LCM(int a, int b)
{

    int i = a > b ? a : b;
    for (i; i <= a * b; i++) {
        if (i % a == 0 && i % b == 0) {

            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Rational& r)
{

    out << r.getnum() << "/" << r.getden();

    return out;
}

Rational operator+(Rational x, Rational y)
{

    Rational temp;
    int temp1;
    int div;
    temp1 = LCM(x.den, y.den);

    temp.num = (int(temp1 / x.den) * x.num) + (int(temp1 / y.den) * y.num);
    temp.den = temp1;

    return temp;
}

int main()
{

    Rational r1(3, 2);
    Rational r2(9, 4);
    Rational r3;
    r3 = r1 + r2;
    cout << r3;

    return 0;
}
```

And I get the error:

> error: ‘LCM’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: make LCM a free function (ie not in Rational class), given that you need it in the friend operator you declared, not in the original class.

Comment: Thanx dude it worked ! Very very thanks!  :)

Comment: FYI: since C++17 there is `std::lcm` and `std::gcd` and the use proper algorithm not the slowest possible you are using.

Comment: How can i get access to that algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that `int Rational::LCM(int a,int b)` does not really have anything to do with the `Rational` class and should probably be a utility function (non-member function), then you would be able to use it anywhere

Comment: Yup i got it ! Thanks a lot for helping out ! :)